# How to force HTML Elements keep a constant width to height ratio without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, svg

Here is an example I made using JavaScript. No matter what dimensions the page is, each brick will always be a 5:2 ratio and there will always be 20 bricks across the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg id="wall" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" width="100%" height="100%" onload="renderBackground();" onresize="renderBackground();">
    </svg>
    <script>
      var wall=document.getElementById("wall");
      function renderBackground()
      {
        var width=window.innerWidth;
        wall.innerHTML="";
        for(y=0;y<window.innerHeight;y+=width/25)
        {
          // Even Bricks
          for(x=0;x<width;x+=width/20)
          {
            createBrick(x,y,width/20,width/50);
          }
          // Odd Bricks
          for(x=0-width/40;x<width;x+=width/20)
          {
            createBrick(x,y+width/50,width/20,width/50);
          }
        }
      }
      function createBrick(x,y,width,height)
      {
        var brick=document.createElementNS(wall.namespaceURI,"rect");
        var shine=document.createElementNS(wall.namespaceURI,"rect");
        var drain=Math.random()*24;
        wall.appendChild(brick);
        wall.appendChild(shine);
        brick.setAttribute("x",x);
        brick.setAttribute("y",y);
        brick.setAttribute("width",width);
        brick.setAttribute("height",height);
        shine.setAttribute("x",x+width/20);
        shine.setAttribute("y",y+height/10);
        shine.setAttribute("width",9*width/10);
        shine.setAttribute("height",height/10);
        brick.setAttribute("style","fill:"+rgb(6*Math.random()+128-drain,12*Math.random()+128-drain,6*Math.random()+128-drain)+";stroke:"+rgb(51,51,68)+";stroke-width:"+String(height/20));
        shine.setAttribute("style","fill:"+rgb(160,160,160));
      }
      function rgb(r,g,b)
      {
        return "rgb("+String(Math.floor(Math.max(Math.min(r,256),0)))+","+String(Math.floor(Math.max(Math.min(g,256),0)))+","+String(Math.floor(Math.max(Math.min(b,256),0)))+")";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**If I were to generate this exact same page with php, removing the JavaScript entirely, how could I force the bricks to keep the same 5:2 ratio without needing to call `renderBackground()` to redraw and adjust their size every time the window is resized?**

I would like to know how to do this on all elements, not just SVG.

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do wth php?

Comment: I want to recreate this page with php and doing so is simple. What isn't simple is getting the bricks to remain at their set ratio when the page is resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IE9 or later, with the exception of a few mobile browsers, CSS accepts dimensions of units "viewport width" (vw) and/or "viewport height" (vh). An element with a width of 5v**w** and a height of 2v**w** will be 5% of the viewport's **width** in **width**, as well as 2% of the viewport's **width** in **height**.

Since you're setting the width and height of an element to a percentage of **just the width** of the viewport, it will maintain a constant aspect ratio.

The catch: It will not work *within* an SVG element. It's strictly a CSS unit. It also *only* considers the whole *viewport's* width or height, not any containing element. Your example takes up the whole screen though, so that's fine.

You will have some problems knowing how many rows to draw though, at least without using JavaScript. You're locking yourself to 20 columns, but the rows depend entirely on the client's aspect ratio.

Comment: That is exactly what I need! In the end, I will only be drawing a set number of rows anyway as the bricks will fade to blackness at a certain point and the page will never be shorter than that point.

Thanks!